# Dealing with 2 Arrays with different sizes

Tags: c, arrays

I have 2 char arrays, and they have different sizes.

I need to subtract one from the other, but I didn't manage to do it with a loop (because they have different sizes).

This is what I've written:

```
for (i = 0; i < text_counter; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j <= key_counter; j++)
   {
       text_out[i] = text_in[i] - (key[i] - '0');
   }
   j = 0;
}
```

`text_counter` counts the number of characters in `text_in`, `key_counter` tracks the number of characters in `key`, and the answer is in a third array which is `test_out`.

If one array is `BCDEFG` and the other is `12` the result should be `AACCEE`

Comment: What do you mean by substract strings ? Can you give an example of what you have / want ?

Comment: those are char arrays
if one is "BCDE"
and the other is "12"
i need to get "AACC"

Comment: Subtracting character by character is nothing at all like checking an entire array for the presence of a character, is it? *Confused*.

Comment: so you mean that if the second one is shorter than the first one, then extend the second one by copying again from the start of it, and then do a character-by-character subtraction

Comment: @MattMcNabb Exactly, sorry English is not my first language and maybe im not expressing myself well

Comment: Just have one counter `i`, and take `key[i % key_length]`

Comment: thanks a lot Logar and mattmcnabb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < text_counter; i++)
{
   text_out[i] = text_in[i] - (key[j] - '0');
   if (j < key_counter)
       j++;
   else
       j = 0;
}
```

Edit : @Matt solution with % seems better :

```
for (i = 0; i < text_counter; i++)
{
   text_out[i] = text_in[i] - (key[i % key_counter] - '0');
}
```